# What pickles is he referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

In [Once Upon a Time in Hollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Hollywood), Cliff drives home from Rick's place and sees a hitchhiker called Pussycat:

> CLIFF: Hello, hot stuff.
>
> Pussycat: Looks like third time's the charm.
>
> CLIFF: **Mm. How were those pickles?**
>
> Pussycat: Real good. They were the fancy kind.

What pickles is he referring to?

Comment: The ones she took from the trash few scenes before. When they "met" first time. Isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very first line on this page says it all: [*Film Review*](https://www.wonderlandmagazine.com/2019/07/30/once-upon-time-hollywood-film-review/)

> A Cadillac screeching around Sunset Boulevard. Barefoot hippies in
>   rainbow crochet stealing pickles out of dumpsters.

Cliff recognized Pussycat as one of those hippies.